# Difference between calling stored procedure with `query` and `callproc` in pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pymssql

I have a stored procedure saved on SQL Server and using pymssql to connect to that database.

I can call this procedure by calling `cursor.query('EXEC FindPerson')` successfully.
But I can't use the method `cursor.callproc('FindPerson', (name,))`, I got this error

> '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

I wonder why I can't call `callproc` method. The reason I want to use `callproc` is to be able to loop different result sets from the procedure.

I also tried to put different stored procedure on this method, regardless what is the parameter I put into, I always got the same error. So it seems that the method `callproc` failed even before hitting the procedure. The question is what the correct way to call a stored procedure?

Below is an example of stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindPerson
    @name VARCHAR(100)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM persons 
    WHERE name = @name
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass name param in tuple.
Try cursor.callproc('FindPerson', (personname,))

Comment: I added the parameter in the code but I forgot to paste it. I got the same error.